# How to use Asterisk for Linphone default chatting?

Tags: asterisk, linphone, freepbx, linphone-sdk

I want to use Linphone default chatting feature with Asterisk. I have tried to use OPENFIRE XMPP but it seems not supporting. Not even returning any status/error.
I am using Asterisk 12

The goal is to use same user credential for Calling + Chatting using Linphone default chatting feature.

If anyone have any idea please share.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

There is no "default chatting", becuase asterisk is PBX, not chat server.

You can write your own using sip message dialplan

https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+SIP+Messaging

Comment: I know Asterisk doesn't have DEFAULT CHATTING, I am using OPENFIRE XMPP that I integrated with Asterisk. I want to use Linphone (softphone) which comes with CHATTING features by default. I am planning to use the same user login credential to work with VOIP + Chatting.  All VOIP related features are working just fine but no luck with CHATTING. It left me confused because it's not returning any error or any status which will let me know whether the OPENFIRE got problem or the Linphone Chat is not supporting it.

Comment: use sip debug,see what client send, google how to handle.